# transform image and then dynamicaly rotate issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to dynamically create div outside image and then perform rotate . i have written the code but image flip is done but m not able see the 3D rotation .

```
$(obj).css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(180deg)");
$(obj).css("transform","rotateY(180deg)");


var imgLeftPos = $(obj).position().left;
var imgTopPos = $(obj).position().top;

$(obj).wrap('<div class="f1_card"></div>');
$(obj).wrap('<div class="front face"></div>');
$(".f1_card").wrap('<div class="f1_container"></div>');
var div = $("<div class='back face'></div>");
$('.face').after(div);
$('.back').css("left",imgLeftPos+"px");
$('.back').css("top",imgTopPos+"px");
var arrId = parseInt(obj.id.substr(2));
console.log("arrId   = "+arrId)
window.setTimeout(function () {

    $(".back").html(imgArr[arrId]);
},900);
```

for second click i have written  code to unflip image and that flip i can see with 3D rotation . whtas the problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to do it the wrong way.

I would sugest you to have all the CSS already done, and tested, and then use your script just to create the div and assign it the class that you have defined in the CSS.